# Thymeleaf with spring i accnot find the solution for template resolver

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

```
<bean id="templateResolver"
      class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
    <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
  ``  <property name="cacheable" value="true" />
</bean>
<bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine">
    <property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver" />
</bean>
```

the error which is giving me is cannot resolve ServletContextTemplateResolver how can i solve it?

Comment: Could you please provide more logs?

Comment: did you add the dependency to   org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-spring3:2.1.4  or org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-spring4:2.1.4 in your pom?

Comment: yes ihad imported jar files  org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-spring3:2.1.4  and iam not using pom.xml it is giving me cannot resolve template resolver